# Django - There's some way to avoid repeat code in all my views?

Tags: jquery, django, view, registration

All templates in my project, have a registration button that only can be seen when you enter as anonimous user. That button open a modal window with two registration forms. The problem it's i must have this code in all my views in order to work. There's some way to avoid repeat the code relative to the registration forms in all my views?

**Clarification:** The code im repeating in all my views it's commented as #USER REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE and #MERCHANT REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE

**MY MODAL WINDOW**:

[image]

**ONE OF MY VIEWS** (75 lines):

```
def patrimonio_view(request, backend_registro_usuario, backend_registro_comerciante, success_url=None, form_class_usuario=None, form_class_comerciante=None,
         disallowed_url='registration_disallowed',
         template_name='home/patrimonio.html',
         extra_context=None):

#PATRIMONIO QUERYS
pat = patrimonio.objects.all()
ciu = ciudad.objects.all()

#USER REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
backend_registro_usuario = get_backend(backend_registro_usuario)
if not backend_registro_usuario.registration_allowed(request):
    return redirect(disallowed_url)
if form_class_usuario is None:
    form_class_usuario = backend_registro_usuario.get_form_class(request)

if "Registrar_usuario" in request.POST:
    form_class_usuario = form_class_usuario(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form_class_usuario.is_valid():
        new_usuario = backend_registro_usuario.register(request, **form_class_usuario.cleaned_data)
        if success_url is None:
            to, args, kwargs = backend_registro_usuario.post_registration_redirect(request, new_usuario)
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(success_url)
else:
    form_class_usuario = form_class_usuario()

if extra_context is None:
    extra_context = {}
context = RequestContext(request)
for key, value in extra_context.items():
    context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value

#MERCHANT REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
backend_registro_comerciante = get_backend(backend_registro_comerciante)
if not backend_registro_comerciante.registration_allowed(request):
    return redirect(disallowed_url)
if form_class_comerciante is None:
    form_class_comerciante = backend_registro_comerciante.get_form_class(request)

if "Registrar_comerciante" in request.POST:
    form_class_comerciante = form_class_comerciante(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form_class_comerciante.is_valid():
        new_comerciante = backend_registro_comerciante.register(request, **form_class_comerciante.cleaned_data)
        if success_url is None:
            to, args, kwargs = backend_registro_comerciante.post_registration_redirect(request, new_comerciante)
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(success_url)
else:
    form_class_comerciante = form_class_comerciante()

if extra_context is None:
    extra_context = {}
context = RequestContext(request)
for key, value in extra_context.items():
    context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value


#WE OBTAIN THE USERS FOR EACH GROUP
usuario_group = Group.objects.get(name="usuario").user_set.all()
comerciante_group = Group.objects.get(name="comerciante").user_set.all()

#RENDER
return render_to_response(template_name,
                          {'form_registro_usuario': form_class_usuario, 
                          'form_registro_comerciante': form_class_comerciante,
                           'patrimonio':pat, 
                           'ciudad':ciu,
                           'usuario_group': usuario_group,
                           'comerciante_group': comerciante_group,
                           },

                          context_instance=context)
```

**SOLUTION - REFACTORED CODE** (29 lines):

```
def patrimonio_view(request, 
     template_name='home/patrimonio.html'):

#PATRIMONIO QUERYS
pat = patrimonio.objects.all()
ciu = ciudad.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if "Registrar_usuario" in request.POST:
        #USER REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
        return register_usuario()

    if "Registrar_comerciante" in request.POST:
        #MERCHANT REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
        return register_comerciante()

#WE OBTAIN THE USERS FROM EACH GROUP
usuario_group = Group.objects.get(
   name="usuario").user_set.all()
comerciante_group = Group.objects.get(
   name="comerciante").user_set.all()

#RENDER
return render_to_response(template_name,{
   'patrimonio':pat, 
   'ciudad':ciu,
   'usuario_group': usuario_group,
   'comerciante_group': comerciante_group,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The code commented as #USER REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE and #MERCHANT REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE will exist in all my views, since  the modal window's form can be used from any of my templates when you are not logged.

Comment: Why not just use AJAX to handle the FORM posts, so you can isolate the views without having to embed all that code in every single view?

Comment: Im searching documentation about it. By the moment this is the best i founf it: http://ericwconner.com/?p=126

Comment: There are quite a few questions on SO about Django and AJAX, too. A few searches should net you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I miss something, just tell me I will fix it. Sorry I just can't understand other codes.

```
def patrimonio_view(request, 
         backend_registro_usuario, backend_registro_comerciante, 
         form_class_usuario=None, form_class_comerciante=None,
         disallowed_url='registration_disallowed', template_name='home/patrimonio.html',
         extra_context=None, success_url=None):

    #PATRIMONIO QUERYS
    pat = patrimonio.objects.all()
    ciu = ciudad.objects.all()

    form_class_usuario = form_class_usuario()
    form_class_comerciante = form_class_comerciante()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "Registrar_usuario" in request.POST:
            #USER REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
            return user_registration(request, 
                backend_registro_usuario, 
                disallowed_url, 
                form_class_usuario, 
                success_url
                )

        if "Registrar_comerciante" in request.POST:
            #MERCHANT REGISTRATION FORM RELATIVE
            return merchant_registration(request, 
                backend_registro_comerciante, 
                disallowed_url, 
                form_class_comerciante, 
                success_url
                )

    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value


    #Obtenemos los usuarios de cada grupo
    usuario_group = Group.objects.get(
       name="usuario").user_set.all()
    comerciante_group = Group.objects.get(
       name="comerciante").user_set.all()

    #RENDER
    return render_to_response(template_name,{
       'form_registro_usuario': form_class_usuario, 
       'form_registro_comerciante': form_class_comerciante,
       'patrimonio':pat, 
       'ciudad':ciu,
       'usuario_group': usuario_group,
       'comerciante_group': comerciante_group,
    }, context_instance=context)

def user_registration(request, 
        backend_registro_usuario, form_class_usuario, 
        disallowed_url, success_url):

    backend_registro_usuario = get_backend(backend_registro_usuario)
    if not backend_registro_usuario.registration_allowed(request):
        return redirect(disallowed_url)
    if form_class_usuario is None:
        form_class_usuario = backend_registro_usuario.get_form_class(request)

    form_class_usuario = form_class_usuario(data=request.POST, 
                                            files=request.FILES)
    if form_class_usuario.is_valid():
        new_usuario = backend_registro_usuario.register(request, 
            **form_class_usuario.cleaned_data)
        if success_url is None:
            to, args, kwargs = backend_registro_usuario.post_registration_redirect(request, new_usuario)
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(success_url)

def merchant_registration(request, 
        backend_registro_comerciante, form_class_comerciante, 
        disallowed_url, success_url):

    backend_registro_comerciante = get_backend(backend_registro_comerciante)
    if not backend_registro_comerciante.registration_allowed(request):
        return redirect(disallowed_url)
    if form_class_comerciante is None:
        form_class_comerciante = backend_registro_comerciante.get_form_class(request)

    form_class_comerciante = form_class_comerciante(data=request.POST, 
                                                    files=request.FILES)
    if form_class_comerciante.is_valid():
        new_comerciante = backend_registro_comerciante.register(request, 
            **form_class_comerciante.cleaned_data)
        if success_url is None:
            to, args, kwargs = backend_registro_comerciante.post_registration_redirect(request, new_comerciante)
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(success_url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much catherine! I was not very sure about how to use methods in views. All it's clean and working now. I posted a even more refactored version based in your help, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options for including code in multiple views: inclusion tags, context processors and template inheritance. It just depends on which one makes the most sense for your setup.

A [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) would probably be your best option to keep conditional logic out of the template, since you need to check to see if the user is anonymous, which you could do server-side in the processor:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def your_context_processor(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        return {'extra_context': render_to_string('anonymous-only-content.html')}
    else:
        return {}
```

Then in your template, you can just do:

```
{{ extra_context }}
```

where you need the anonymous-only code to render, if that variable is populated. These are simple examples, but will hopefully give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brandom! I tried to use a context processor to render the html document that contains my form but fields are not show and submit button doesn´t work: http://oi47.tinypic.com/2nsz4hi.jpg

The same thing happends when i use {% include %}

Comment: Hmm. Without seeing the exact implementation of the context processor, it's difficult to determine why your content won't show up. If you've also tried using a template tag, and it's not showing up, you may have an unhandled exception somewhere in that code, which would cause Django to swallow the exception at the template layer.